# Javascript clear listeners and variables

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am about to ajaxify my website, but I have observed in some highly ajaxified websites like facebook itself that if you browse for quite some time without refreshing your browser gets slower, respectively more ram is being used and I suppose that is due to javascript "leftovers". It is kind of needless to ask this question if facebook's developers fail to accomplish this but hey, you only lose if you don't try. So the question is "is there a way I can clear variables and listeners from the previous page before loading the new one?". Thank you in advance!

Comment: Key question: what (if any) JS framework are you using?  jQuery seems to be just about Everybody's Favorite, but I'd encourage you to look at Dojo, too.

Comment: I do use jquery, unfortunately. Thanks for the advice, sure will!

Comment: Fair enough.  Here's a very good link on jQuery performance optimization tips: [Your jQuery: Now With 67% Less Suck](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/).  This link also has many tips applicable to jQuery (and JS in general):[Improving performance of Dojo-based web applications](http://www.lazutkin.com/blog/2007/02/01/improving-performance/).  'Hope that helps!

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for the useful material. Surprisingly I have been doing exactly what's said in the first article without knowing `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the browser since each browser does its own Garbage Collection. You can however delete variables and HTML elements and if the GC thinks it can reclaim some memory, it will.

I suggest using some developer tools to actually watch the memory usage in real-time. In Chrome you can create a <s>profile</s> timeline and watch the memory usage grow/shrink. So you can actually see in real-time the effects your code have on memory management.

For testing I like to run cleanup code on a button click so I can know exactly when the code ran and how the memory usage was affected by the code.

And hey, since you're in there playing with dev. tools now, check-out the other tools available to you, they are amazingly helpful.

Comment: That's a good point, sure will try that. Do you know if firebug has such option. I've been using chrome my whole life and I recently switched to firefox and it's now like I'm in a jungle :D

Comment: @php_nub_qq I haven't developed with Firefox in a while, if it's not something you can get right in their dev. tools, I'd suspect that you can get it as an addon. I can say for sure that the Chrome dev. tools rock.

Comment: "whole life", lol. 5 year old AJAX programmer? @php_nub_qq: Ctrl+Shift+K or Firebug and use F12.